# How to detect the coordinates of a custom UIView on CPTPlotspace?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

In my App, I am using Coreplot to draw a CPTScatterPlot. Now i want to do a scanner on the chart and this animation of UIView (a line) should be like a Line aligned with Y-axis and travels through x=0 to whatever the last value of x is.

I want to perform an action based on the y value while this custom UIView (scanner) travels.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

i have something similar in an app of mine, the way i went about it was to add a bar graph on top of the scatter plot, i used that bar graph to represent the line that tracks the user's touch.
then i have a UIView that is overlaid on the plot and tracks the scatter plot touches and displays details of the point being touched.

if you just want to display a line, adding a bar graph is probably the easiest, then you don't have to worry about plot space coordinates vs superview coordinates.
the bar graph data source is only returning a value for the location the user is touching, with a height to match the size of the scatter plot.

the quick version is you can use handlePlotTouchEventInSpace:atPoint:isNewEvent to track the user's touches on the graph.

from there you can use the plotPoint:forPlotAreaViewPoint method on the plot space to get the coordinates of the touch.

something like this is a good starting point. it's a bit of a journey to get it all working, but its not too bad once you get the puzzle started.

```
-(void)handlePlotTouchEventInSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space atPoint:(CGPoint)point isNewEvent:(BOOL)newEvent {
    NSDecimal plotPoint[2]; 
    CPTXYPlotSpace *xySpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)space; 
    [xySpace plotPoint:plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:point];
```

after that plotPoint will contain the x and y location of the touch inside the plot space.

Comment: I already have a Line graph drawn and i want to give an impression of scanning this graph by animating a line from left to right corner of the graph and in the same time i want to know when the line crosses every x coordinate.

Comment: in that case you should be able to take the CGPoint you get in handlePlotTouchEventInSpace and send it to the indexOfVisiblePointClosestToPlotAreaPoint method on the scatterPlot and get an index back. you'll just use that index as your one datapoint in the bar graph, and reload the bar graph as the user moves

Comment: But there will be no touch in my app.

Comment: Use a timer to update the position of the scan line. Every time the timer fires, call `-reloadData` on the secondary plot that draws the scan line (scatter plot or bar plot) and have the datasource provide an updated position.